# Error: Maximum recursive updates exceeded when trying to render fetched data

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to fetch some data from an API, do some data formatting, and then feed that data to my Chart component but I get the following error when trying to do so:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
<template>
    <apexchart type="rangeBar" :options="chartOptions" :series="sceneAttributes"></apexchart>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

setup() {
        const sceneAttributes = ref([]);

        fetch(`apiUrl`)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            // const atts = [];
            for (const key in data.sceneAttributeValues) {
                data.sceneAttributeValues[key].forEach(att => {
                let obj = {};
                obj.data = [];
                obj.data.push({
                    x: att.attributeValue.attributeId,
                    y: [att.from, att.to+1]
                })
                // obj.from = att.from;
                // obj.to = att.to;
                if (att.attributeValue.strValue) {
                    obj.name = att.attributeValue.strValue;
                }
                
                if (att.attributeValue.intValue) {
                    obj.name = att.attributeValue.intValue;
                }
                if (att.attributeValue.boolValue) {
                    obj.name = att.attributeValue.boolValue;
                }
                sceneAttributes.value.push(obj)
                })
                
            }
            // End of first for loop

        });

         return { sceneAttributes }

    }
}
```

I have to do this convoluted data formatting because the raw data I get from the fetched JSON.

```
{
  "sceneAttributeValues": {
    "Object Distance": [
      {
        "attributeValue": {
          "attributeId": "Object Distance",
          "intValue": 39
        },
        "from": 29,
        "to": 123
      }
    ],
    "Object Detection": [
      {
        "attributeValue": {
          "attributeId": "Object Detection",
          "strValue": "Yes"
        },
        "from": 79,
        "to": 122
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can´t reproduce it from the provided code to help you. But you can simply locate the reason for this by comment out everything step by step in `.then(data => {`. Your error tells you, that something is updating itself and is therefore captured in an endless loop.

Comment: Yes, if I tried printing each line to the console and it didn't throw anything. Essentially, the error gets thrown whenever I try to assign the array I've been populating with objects to the array that I use in the chart component.

Comment: As you declare `const sceneAttributes = ref([]);` you maybe run into this, because a `const` isn't meant to be changed after declaration. Try to use `let sceneAttributes = ref([]);`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess using AXIOS for requesting an API might help you

Here is the document on how to use axios in Vue : [Using Axios to Consume APIs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)

Don't forget to install and import axios before using it , To install axios you need to run this command in your project directory :

> npm i axios

Here you can find more info about axios : [axios-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Tried using axios instead of fetch, got the same error. I don't think the way I'm fetching the data here is the problem.